# How to find $n$ if $a^n \equiv r \pmod m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

In particular I'm looking at the problem:

> \begin{align*}
> 3^{n_1} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
> 5^{n_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
> 7^{n_3} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
> \end{align*}

And I want to find $n_1, n_2, n_3$.

I've come up with one way, using binomial theorem:

\begin{align*}
3^{n_1} &= (4-1)^{n_1} = 4 \lambda_1 + (-1)^{n_1} \\
5^{n_2} &= (4+1)^{n_2} = 4 \lambda_2 + 1 \\
7^{n_3} &= (8-1)^{n_3} = 4 \lambda_3 + (-1)^{n_3} \\
\end{align*}

From where we see that $n_1$ and $n_3$ have to be even integers.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Can this be done using modular arithmetic? And
2. Can this more general case be solved using modular arithmetic?
   $$a^n \equiv r \pmod m$$ for given $a, r, \text{ and } m$.

Comment: This is the _discrete logarithm_ problem and is not easy to solve when $m$ is large -- or at least we _hope_ it is not easy to solve; a feasible method to solve this problem would break many public-key cryptosystems, such as RSA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look just a bit closer to the problem

\begin{align*}
3^{n_1} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
5^{n_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
7^{n_3} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
\end{align*}

Simplifies to

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n_1} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
1^{n_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
(-1)^{n_3} &\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
\end{align*}

which simplifies to $n_1$ and $n_3$ are even and $n_2$ can be any integer.

Comment: Gosh, how did I miss that!! And what about when the numbers ($3, 5, 7$ and $4$) aren't so "nice"?

Comment: @AritraDas ->  When they aren't so nice takes about a chapter of a good number theory book to explain.